# qsort with limited boundaries in K&R | sorting procedure doesn't continue on next positions in strings

Tags: c, pointers, qsort, kernighan-and-ritchie

Sorry to bother You with yet another question about K&R programs.
But again some things are not clear to me.
The program below is used to sort lines saved by readlines function (is it really saving them?) For that purpose we create an array of pointers pointing to each of these lines.

Questions:
[1] Why do we pass `qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);` I mean nlines-1 and not just nlines ?

[2] Suppose I entered two lines:

bravo

alfa

now they're pointed from array (I'll make a visualization so don't get mad seeing chars in brackets ;))

*v[] == [lineptr[0] - pointer to bravo][lineptr[1] - pointer to alfa]

according to the algorithm: lineptr[0] is the pivot, so we swap them; last = 0; entering for loop: strcmp of  - lineptr[1] is not lexically smaller than lineptr[0]; incrementing i is already finished so we exit for loop. Now we swap last = 0 with left = 0, so nothing happens. They're already in place.

BUT WHAT IF they begin with the same letter eg. abravo and alfa, how would qsort go on to next letter if it only operates on array's indexes from left to right meaning different number of lines not next chars in examined strings.

Please correct me, because all those pointers are driving me crazy.

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINES 5000 /* max #lines to be sorted */
char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /* pointers to text lines */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);
/* sort input lines */
main()
{
    int nlines;
    /* number of input lines read */
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
        qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("error: input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
#define MAXLEN 1000 /* max length of any input line */
int getline(char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
/* readlines: read input lines */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];
    nlines = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if (nlines >= maxlines || p = alloc(len) == NULL)
            return -1;
        else {
            line[len-1] = '\0'; /* delete newline */
            strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
        }
    return nlines;
}
/* writelines: write output lines */
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
        printf("%s\n", lineptr[i]);
}

/* qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order */
void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);
    if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
        return;
    /* fewer than two elements */
    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
    last = left;

    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
        if (strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR HELP

Comment: it is a bit confusing that you name your function qsort when there is a function in stdlib that is called the same but has another signature.

Comment: +1 @AndersK: he didn't include `<stdlib.h>` so he can use the identifier `qsort` for whatever he wants ... but it's a bad idea anyway (see page 108 of K&R).

Comment: ...because adding an include later on might break previously working code, potentially in subtle ways, which can be *quite* confusing. Stay away from standard-defined identifiers.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bad idea, especially as stdlib is ... a pretty standard library to use. But he's only implementing it for the purposes of a textbook assignment, and if he did want to write something 'real' he'd use `quicksort` from stdlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp` compares two strings for lexicographic order. This will take care of using the whole string for comparison, not just the first character.

And the parameter `right` takes the index of the right-most index to sort on. If you have an array of length 10, the first element is 0 and the last is 9 (i.e. 10 - 1, which is `right -1`). The clue is in the line `for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)`, which loops i from `left+1` to `right` including both values.

You called it `qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);`, so it will include the `0`th (first) element of the array and the `nlines-1` (last) element.

Comment: Big thanks! Can You check if that text I've written is proper? "" *v[] == [lineptr[0] - pointer to bravo][lineptr[1] - pointer to alfa] which according to the algorithm: lineptr[0] is the pivot, so we swap them; last = 0; entering for loop: strcmp of - lineptr[1] is not lexically smaller than lineptr[0]; incrementing i is already finished so we exit for loop.""      I'm curious how lines are marked inside that array of pointers since after swapping I'm sure we can't name lineptr[1] that way since if would be now at position [0] in the array